# Getting error while connecting to mongo in aws lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to connect to mongo database using `mongodb` but its throwing error unable to resolve.

This is my mongo connect fucntion

```
const {
    MongoClient,
    ObjectId,
} = require('mongodb');


const {
    MERCURY_MONGO_DB_URL,
} = process.env;
 
const initialize_mongodb_database_connection = async () => {
    
    //
    // Create a new MongoClient
    //
    const connection = new MongoClient(MERCURY_MONGO_DB_URL, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });

    // Use connect method to connect to the Server
    connection.connect((err) => {

        if (err != null) {

            console.log(`MongoDB Connection :: Error :: ${err}`);
            process.exit(1);

        } else {

            const db = connection.db('demo');
            return db;
            global.ObjectId = ObjectId;
            console.log('MongoDB Connection :: Ready');

        }
    
    });

};

module.exports = {
    initialize_mongodb_database_connection,
};
```

And this is where I am trying to use it but getting error

```
var db = await initialize_mongodb_database_connection();

const data = await db.collection(`access_log_${result.student_uuid}`)
                .find(where)
                .toArray();
console.log(data)
```

I am getting error of this `Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined`
where actually I have data at collection `access_log_1747386c-9577-4073-b818-649db0ce9d50`
not sure why it isn't working? I have that collection in my db.

Can any one help here? Also I am developing this for aws lamdba

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying the `db` object is undefined. When looking at your `initialize_mongodb_database_connection` function, you're not returning the promise returned by `MongoClient#connect`.

```js
const initialize_mongodb_database_connection = async () => {
    ...

    return connection.connect((err) => {
        ...
    });
};
```